# good way to go about doing page excerpts

Tags: php, facebook, curl, file-get-contents

I'm looking to achieve the effect facebook has when you put a link into a message - they scrape the title and some images from it.
I noticed they also do it extremely quickly. (they must cache some of the re-sent items?)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this with PHP?
Can I somehow quickly grab the `<title>` block of the page without cURLing the entire thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to grab the entire page and use a [HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to rip out the title tag.

Like you said, if you want fast speeds consider caching the results.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks, i'm currently using simplehtmldom.. its just too slow!
plus PHP runs out of memory doing bigger sites, and I feel that there must be a better solution out there...

Comment: I don't know much about cURL, but does it download everything? You could restrict it to just the HTML.

Comment: @daniel: SimpleHtmlDom is great, but as you mentioned it's slow. Try using phps DOM class -> http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php